# In which cases is scanf safe in terms of overflow? And in which cases must it necessarily be replaced by another function such as fgets?

Tags: c, scanf, overflow, fgets, gets

It is usually said that `scanf` is not a safe function. Clang and GCC do not issue any warnings, but MSVC does not even compile (unless you include _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS):

> Error C4996 'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe.

- Does this mean that in some cases `scanf` is guarantee to not overflow and in others not?
- If so, which exactly are these cases?

Another function also for reading data is `gets`

- Are there cases where `gets` can be used safely or should it be avoided altogether?

It is usually suggested as an alternative to `scanf` and `gets` the use of `fgets`.

- How is `fgets` more secure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Functions `scanf` and `gets` for string processing

The [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) function [is safe for string processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430303/disadvantages-of-scanf/2430978#2430978) because there is a specific field to delimit the length of the string. This is shown in the following example.

```
// Example 01   
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 7

int main(void)
{
    char city[SIZE];
    printf("Insert the name of your city: ");    // Columbus
    scanf("%6s", city);
    printf("The city is: %s", city);             // Columb

    return 0;
}

/* ## Output ##
 * Insert the name of your city: Columbus
 * The city is: Columb
 */
```

If the user enters for the name of the city `Columbus`, a [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) will not occur, since `scanf` will limit itself to trying to store only the first 6 characters of the string in `city`, according to the `%6s` instruction (in addition to inserting at the end `\0`, which is the null character: [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)). Therefore, when the result is shown on the screen, it appears `Columb` as the name of the city.

The drawback is that the string length limit cannot be entered as an argument directly, unlike [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf). More details in the **Annex**.

String processing can also be performed by the function `gets`. However, `gets` does not have any delimiter fields and will read until it finds a newline or the end of the file (EOF). Rewriting the previous example for `gets`:

```
// Example 02   
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 7

int main(void)
{
    char city[SIZE];
    printf("Insert the name of the city: ");    // Columbus
    gets(city);
    printf("The city is: %s", city);            // ???

    return 0;
}

/* ## Possible Output ##
 * Insert the name of the city: Columbus
 * The city is: Columbus
 */
```

`Gets` tries to store the complete string in `city`, which is not possible, after all, `city` does not support a string of 8 characters. In the tested case, `gets` invaded adjacent memory addresses to write the part of the string that could not be stored in `city`, resulting in a buffer overflow. If a string is long enough, it is expected that in addition to a buffer overflow, it will also causes a segmentation fault (more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685413/what-is-the-difference-between-a-segmentation-fault-and-a-stack-overflow) and [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-different-between-Buffer-Overflow-with-Segmentation-Fault)). Buffer overflow is one of the main vulnerabilities exploited by hackers and therefore special attention should be paid to this issue (video: [buffer overflow attack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1S0aBV-Waeo). Text: [Buffer Overflow Exploitation](https://dhavalkapil.com/blogs/Buffer-Overflow-Exploit/)). Thus, due to the lack of a field that defines the length of the string to be stored, it is impossible to read strings safely with `gets` (and reading strings is the only function of `gets`). Therefore, `gets` should never be used and has been completely [removed from the language as of C11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets).

### Functions `scanf` and `fgets` for arithmetic data processing

In addition to strings, `scanf` also reads arithmetic data (integer and floating point values). However, [for this case, `scanf` is not safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430303/disadvantages-of-scanf/2430978#2430978), and there is no guarantee protection against undefined behavior. The following code illustrates this. Since the [C standard specifies only the absolute minimum value of integer types](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf), the value of `LONG_MIN` and `LONG_MAX` are implementation-dependent, but it is mandatory that `LONG_MIN <= -2147483647` and `LONG_MAX >= +2147483647`).

```
// Example 03    
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define SIZE 100

int main(void) {

    long a;
    char buffer[SIZE];

    printf("Enter a number: ");            // 2147483648 (LONG_MAX + 1)
    int success = scanf("%ld", &a);
    printf("a = %ld", a);
    getchar();

    printf("\nEnter a number: ");          // 2147483648
    fgets(buffer, SIZE, stdin);
    long b = strtol(buffer, NULL, 10);
    if (b == LONG_MAX && errno == ERANGE) {
        printf("b: Overflow!\n");
    }
    else if (b == LONG_MIN && errno == ERANGE) {
        printf("b: Underflow!\n");
    }
    printf("b = %ld", b);

    return 0;
}

/* ## Possible Output ##
 * Enter a number:  2147483648
 * a = -2147483648
 * Enter a number: 2147483648
 * b: Overflow!
 * b = 2147483647
 */
```

The user enters a sufficiently large number that `long` is unable to store (read **Note**). `Scanf` reads the number and returns 1 (the return of `scanf` indicates the number of values ​​successfully assigned). However, overflow happens and according to the C Standard integer overflow results in undefined behavior. In the test carried out with the example, to the variable `a` was assigned the value `-2147483648`. This indicates that there was what is known as [wraparound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45484643/wrap-around-of-integers-in-c). However, [`scanf` does not allow testing integer overflows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28007600/detecting-integral-overflow-with-scanf). The situation can be mitigated by seeking to impose a limit on the value read. Considering a `long` where `LONG_MAX` is `+2147483647`, it is possible to impose a limit by writing `scanf("%9ld", number)`. Note that a value with 10 digits (`%10ld`) would already open room for overflow (`+9 999 999 999` > `+2 147 483 647`). However, imposing the limit of 9 digits, what happens is that there is a range of numbers that are valid (`long` is able to store), but the code excludes from the possibilities. On the other hand, `fgets` offers protection. First, in the code, `fgets(buffer, SIZE, stdin)` limits the value read, preventing the occurrence of a buffer overflow, which could be critical. Next, `strtol` performs the conversion to `long`: `long b = strtol(buffer, NULL, 10)`. It is not possible to store the value in the `long` type, so `strtol`:

1. Returns the largest possible integer: `LONG_MAX`. With this, it avoids the occurrence of a overflow of the variable `b`.
2. Sets the [`errno`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/errno) flag to [`ERANGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/errno-constants?view=msvc-170) indicating that an error has occurred, specifically a value processed with excessively large magnitude.

It is worthy noting that [`scanf` does not set `errno`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28007600/detecting-integral-overflow-with-scanf), preventing a similar strategy from being adopted in `scanf`.

Note that `fgets` logic is safe. Even if an overflow-based attack is attempted, all behaviors are well defined. There will be no buffer overflow and no integer overflow of variable `b`, which will necessarily be in its validity range.

If it's a `float` type, the situation is more subtle. According to IEEE 754, if a number is too large to be stored in a float type, it must be assigned to the variable the special value `inf` or `-inf` (IEEE 754 topic 7.4 and covered [here](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X0800800207) [topic 2 Overflow and underflow] and [here](https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-00779764/document) [topic: 2.3.2 Overflow]). However, this is not in the C standard. Therefore, a compiler may or may not reproduce the behavior described in IEEE 754. If there is compliance with IEEE 754, the behavior of `scanf`, when reading an excessively large number, will be to assign to the variable of type `float` the special value `inf` or `-inf`. This is defined behavior and, in this sense, safe. This is illustrated in the code below.

```
// Example 04
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {

    float a;
    printf("Enter a number: ");               // 2E40
    int success = scanf("%f", &a);            // 1

    if (isinf(a)) {
        printf("Underflow or Overflow!\n");   // Underflow or Overflow!
    }
    printf("a = %f", a);                      // inf

    return 0;
}

/* ## Possible Output ##
 * Enter a number 2E40
 * Underflow or Overflow!
 * a = inf
 */
```

This code has been tested on MSVC, Clang, GCC and TCC. In all cases, was assigned to the variable `a` special value `inf`. However, C compilers are not required to comply with IEEE 754 and therefore `scanf` is not safe for storing floating point numbers.

On the other hand, the `fgets` strategy involves two sequential operations:

1. `fgets` stores the value read as a string in a array of chars
2. `strtof` converts the string to float

The first operation is safe, as show in example 3. The second operation is also safe, since its behavior is determined by the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf). If the value converted by `strtof` is outside the valid range, then `HUGE_VALF` is returned ([reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof)). With this, there is the certainty of a defined behavior.

Therefore, the processing of floating point values by `fgets` strategy  is safe. The code below is `fgets` version of Example 4.

```
// Example 05
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 50    

int main(void) {

    char buffer[SIZE];
    float a;
    printf("Enter a number: ");           // 2E40        
    fgets(buffer, SIZE, stdin);
    buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0;    // remove '\n'    
    a = strtof(buffer, NULL);

    if (isinf(a)) {
        printf("Underflow or Overflow!\n");
    }
    printf("a = %f", a);                  // +inf

    return 0;
}

/* ## Output ##
 * Enter a number: 2E40
 * Underflow or Overflow!
 * a = inf
 */
```

### Function `fgets` for processing strigs

In addition to arithmetic data processing, `fgets` can also be used for string processing, as a substitute of `scanf`. The first example with `scanf` can be adapted to an alternative version with `fgets`.

```
// Example 06
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 7

int main(void) {
    char city[SIZE];
    printf("Insert the name of the city: ");   // Columbus
    fgets(city, SIZE, stdin);
    printf("The city is: %s", city);           // Columb

    return 0;
}

/* ## Output ##
 * Insert the name of the city: Columbus
 * The city is: Columb
 */
```

Like `scanf`, `fgets` also provides buffer overflow protection processing strings. However, unlike `scanf`, in `fgets` the maximum value for the number of characters read can be inserted directly as an argument and in this case was inserted through `SIZE` (more information in the **Annex**).

#### Annex

With `printf` it is possible to insert the value for the delimiter field through an argument. The following example illustrates this:

```
// Example 07
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 6

int main(void) {

    char country[20] = "Canada";
    printf("%.*s \n", SIZE, country);    // Canada
    printf("%.6s \n", country);          // Canada

    return 0;
}

/* ## Output ##
 * Canada
 * Canada
 */
```

For `scanf` the only **direct strategy** is analogous to the second `printf`. This is a disadvantage since the delimiter field through an argument, unlike the "hardcoded" strategy, allows to easily work with cases where the value comes from:

1. A variable from another file
2. A user-entered argument

and it is still convenient if used in multiple `printf`.

**Note**: `scanf` can receive the value for the delimiter field through  andargument, but not directly. Details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17314796/max-string-length-using-scanf-ansi-c/19415909#19415909) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621394/how-to-prevent-scanf-causing-a-buffer-overflow-in-c/1621973#1621973).

#### Note

A buffer overflow can be defined as an invasion of memory regions not belonging to the variable. In an integer overflow (or floating overflow) this invasion does not necessarily happen. When referring to this type of overflow, it is alluded to **the attempt** to assign a value to a variable that is unable to store such a value due to its excessive magnitude. For an integer overflow, this configures undefined behavior, which could result in a buffer overflow (memory intrusion), a wraparound, etc.

#### Additional Topic:

#### Particularities of `scanf`, `gets` and `fgets` processing strings

The default behavior of the function  `scanf` is to stop reading at the first [whitespace](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) found ([reference](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.1.0?topic=functions-fscanf-scanf-sscanf-read-format-data)). However, the whitespace is left in the input buffer. So the following code is not correct:

```
// Example 08
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 20

int main() {

    char city[SIZE];
    char state[SIZE];

    printf("City: ");            // Columbus  
    scanf("%19s", city);
    printf("State: ");
    fgets(state, 20, stdin);

    return 0;
}

/* ## Possible Output ##
 * City: Columbus
 * State:
 */
```

What happens is that `scanf` reads the city entered by the user and leaves in the input buffer `\n`. With that, `fgets` reads the rest of the input buffer (`\n`) and stores it in the variable `state`. As a result, the user cannot enter the `state`. To correct this code it is necessary to insert `getchar` after each `scanf`. However, this protection fails if the user enters the following sequence for the variable `city`: Columbus <kbd>space</kbd> <kbd>enter</kbd>. The program returns to the initial problem: `getchar` will remove space from the buffer, but the newline will remain in the buffer. An alternative to solve this problem is to replace `getchar` with `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')`. This will clear from the input buffer everything after the last character processed by `scanf` until it finds a newline or the end of the file. So for this solution, each `getchar` would be replaced by:

```
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n');
```

For both cases, `fgets` already intrinsically provides the necessary protection. That's because `fgets` stops reading only when it finds a newline, the end of file or when it reaches the maximum number of characters, whichever comes first ([reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets)). In this case, the newline is what happens first and it is included in the associated variable (in this case, `city` or `state`) and removed from the input buffer. Similarly, `gets` reads until a newline or the end of the file is encountered. If a new line is found, it is included in the associated variable ([reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets)).

Finally, several particularities of scanf and fgets are presented [here](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html).

### Conclusion

> Does this mean that in some cases scanf is guarantee to not overflow
> and in others not?

Yes. String processing can be safely performed by `scanf`. However, when processing integer or floating point values there is no guarantee.

> Are there cases where gets can be used safely or should it be avoided altogether?

It should be avoided completely. The `gets` function is safe only in environments where limits are imposed on `stdin`, which is a very specific case.

> How is fgets more secure?

The function `fgets` provides security for both string and arithmetic data processing (integer and floating point).